# How to make a font / letter filled with dots using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, font-design

Is it possible to fill a shape or letter ( alphabet, Indic etc ) with random dots ? ie, when the base is removed, the letter will appear as if made of dots. Something like we can see below

[image]

My goal is to achieve this for an Indic language. I hope it as simple as drawing a circle or diamond and then make it fit inside the shape. So that the letter of the font will look like they are made up of dots.

I am an Inkscape + Ubuntu 18.04 user. Thanks.

Comment: It would be much easier to use a dot matrix font.  There are some [here](https://www.1001fonts.com/dot-matrix-fonts.html).  Sorry I don't know if there any made for Indic scripts.

Comment: You could fill letters with a custom pattern in Inkscape, however it's highly unlikely that the dots will fit perfectly within the letters as per your example.

Comment: Maybe some method to fill in a square with circles, perfectly. And if we can do the same for any shape. Please ignore the font part. I just mentioned it. At this point asking about filling a shape with circles or diamond shaped pieces seems more productive. Thanks

Comment: Are you really asking about random dots, or dots in a grid? For random, there's a way to do this with the spray tool - but it looks more like you're actually looking for the opposite of 'random'.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned grid. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use a dot matrix font for this, because it would be much easier, and look more like your example. There are many available online such as [those here](https://www.1001fonts.com/dot-matrix-fonts.html). I have no affiliation with that website.

Another method is to make a custom pattern in Inkscape, and use the pattern as a fill.

This pattern is made of one square with a black fill, and then another square with no fill on top, to make a space around it.

This example is zoomed in so you can see it. The actual size is small.

[image]

Then select both shapes and do *Object > Pattern > Objects to Pattern*

Next, apply the pattern as a fill to some text in the *Fill and Stroke* panel > *Fill Tab*

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I once published a raster font on my [blog](https://demystifikation.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/matrixfont-improved/), but in iso-latin-15, it is not prepared for Indian fonts, but maybe you can adapt or transform it for your needs.

There is a link in the blogpost, which links to an older explanation and version, which is only available in German, but you should be able to translate it to English with [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator).

I made the characters from holes, to allow them to overlay an image or a filled shape witih gradient. If you have questions about it, I'm glad to try to answer them, although I rarely used the font myself. 
[image]